# .BAT Copy an Excel file in the same folder and rename it

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a .bat to duplicate several excel files in the same folder but to rename them:
Copy this excel file in the same directory
C:\Funds\Report 12-16
Rename it
C:\Funds\Report 01-17

Copy this excel file in the same directory
C:\Funds2\Report2 12-16
Rename it
C:\Funds2\Report2 01-17

Answer (score 1):

IMPORTANT: ill assume your file exension is ".xls"

```
@echo off
md temporary
xcopy "%CD%\Report 12-16.xls" "%CD%\temporary"
ren "%CD%\temporary\Report 12-16.xls" "report 01-17.xls"
xcopy "%CD%\temporary\Report 01-17.xls" "%CD%"
del "%CD%\temporary\Report 01-17.xls"
xcopy "%CD%\Report2 12-16.xls" "%CD%\temporary"
ren "%CD%\temporary\Report2 12-16.xls" "Report2 01-17.xls"
xcopy "%CD%\temporary\Report2 01-17" "%CD%"
del "%CD%\temporary\Report2 01-17.xls"
rd /Q temporary
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use of the batch [FOR command](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true).  With FOR you can iterate through the files matching a given pattern, extract parts of the filename and use them to build a command to be performed.

Assuming the files all follow the pattern you indicate in your question, i.e. `<name> <mm-yy>`.xlsx then you could use the following in a batch file 'new_month.cmd':

```
FOR /F "delims= " %%B IN ('dir /b *%1.xlsx') DO copy "%%B %1.xlsx" "%%B %2.xlsx"
```

And call it from the command line with 'new_month.cmd 12-16 01-17'.

The command finds all files matching *12-16.xlsx, splits the filename on the ' ' character defined by 'delims= ' and uses the first token in the results to copy the old file to a new file using date strings %1 and %2 provided as parameters to the batch file on the command line.

Note you can also do this on the command line directly (no batch file required) as:

```
FOR /F "delims= " %B IN ('dir /b *12-16.xlsx') DO copy "%B 12-16.xlsx" "%B 01-17.xlsx"
```